# What is the best practise for handling static content in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to know what is the best way to handle stuff like "help files" in mvc.  I was thinking about this last night and I have a solution but is it a best practice (or good enough practice).  Ignore html files. 
        routes.ignoreroute("{filename}.html");

Alternatively I was thinking that I could do a view with pages for help files. 
Ie /Views/Shared/Help/*helpfilename*

I wanted to avoid the database solution but if that is best practise I am ok with that too. 
          Select html-content where helpcontentname=varible and helplanguage=variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static files are served automatically, there is no need to add any ignore routes.  By default [RouteCollection.RouteExistingFiles = false](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.routeexistingfiles.aspx)

Except:

> **true** if ASP.NET routing handles all requests, even those that match an existing file; otherwise, **false**. The default value is **false**.

The wording is not the best, but basically what it means is; if the file exists and the value is false, IIS will serve the file directly, without starting up an HttpRequest in the ASP.Net pipeline.  (The same reason you don't have to ignore Scripts, StyleSheets, or Images)